# Group Island query with discontinued periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follow,

```
create table #ph (symbol char(2), FisrtDate date, LastDate, value1 int, value2 int, value3 int)
insert into #ph select AA, '20120101', '20130201',  1, 1000, 200
insert into #ph select AA, '20130202', '20150101',  2, 300,  500
insert into #ph select AA, '20150102', '20170101',  2, 300 , 500
insert into #ph select AB, '20120104', '20150101',  1, 200, 500
insert into #ph select AB, '20150104', '20170101',  1, 200, 500
insert into #ph select AB, '20170106', '20170201',  1, 300, 500
```

And I want the output like,

```
Symbol | date_from| date_to  | value1 | value2 | value3
  AA   | 20120101 | 20130201 | 1      | 1000   | 200
  AA   | 20130202 | 20170101 | 1      | 300    | 500
  AB   | 20120104 | 20170101 | 1      | 200    | 500
  AB   | 20120106 | 20170201 | 1      | 300    | 500
```

I am looking for the group island question, but I am confused.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by 'group island' and how it applies to this data.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your data, if I understand correctly you want to display MIN, MAX dates for rows which didn't change value1, value2 and value3?

If so, then simple GROUP BY should do:

```
SELECT symbol, MIN(FirstDate), MAX(LastDate), value1, value2, value3
  FROM #ph
 GROUP BY symbol, value1, value2, value3
```

Comment: You are right. So simple, I am messy in my mind. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Min and Max aggregate functions are to be used based on the requirements. These Aggregate functions will then form the basis of our grouping within the query.

```
SELECT symbol, MIN(FirstDate) as [date_from], MAX(LastDate) as [date_to], value1, value2, value3
FROM #ph
GROUP BY symbol, value1, value2, value3
```